# Accordion header always scroll before the header

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

How can I make the accordion header when click, sticks before the header? I got a lot of content so I need my user see what they have clicked.
I created sample here.

Here's my sample code

```
$(".accordion-box").on('click', '.accord-btn', function() {

   if($(this).hasClass('active')!=true){
     $('.accordion .accord-btn').removeClass('active'); 
   }

   if ($(this).next('.accord-content').is(':visible')){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).next('.accord-content').slideUp(700);
   } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('.accordion .accord-content').slideUp(700);
      $(this).next('.accord-content').slideDown(700);   
    }
});
```

Here's the full version

https://jsfiddle.net/aareyes00/a5ucfpf0/3/

Comment: It's unclear what the issue is. Can you provide more details? The accordion appears to be working fine in your JSFiddle.

Comment: I want the header of each accordion slide up before the header of the site. It's is sticky header. I updated the jsfiddle

Comment: Looks the same as the original.

Comment: sorry here's the updated link https://jsfiddle.net/aareyes00/a5ucfpf0/3/

Comment: If your header includes site navigation and other similar global features, this does not seem like a good idea. A lot of people are under the impression that scrolling is bad, generally, it is not. Accordions should not be used solely to shorten the length of a page but rather to break up content that speaks to specific user groups. Groups that won't care about what's in another accordion beside theirs.